# Python Tkinter Issue with Treeview + SQLite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

So I'm having issues when trying to edit records on the Tkinter interface of this Python Database GUI in which I am utilising Treeview and SQLite. I'm trying to select one of the existing records, and edit the data in a pop-up window, and for the original data to be overwritten by the new data. I am getting an this error `query_result = cursor.execute(query, parameters) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error`

Here is my code, not sure whether I've added parameters I don't need, any help is appreciated. The code below is within a class, is indented as needed and has the functioning code, just didn't need to include for the questions purpose.

**The problem is within this section of the code, not sure which part though!**

```
def editing(self):
    self.message['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.message['text'] = 'Please, select record!'
        return

    name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
    current_position =  self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
    current_gamesplayed =  self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
    current_goals =  self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][2]
    current_assists =  self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][3]
    current_cleansheets =  self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][4]

    self.edit_controller = Toplevel()
    self.edit_controller.title('Edit Player Record')

    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'Current Name:').grid(row=0, column=1)
    Entry(self.edit_controller, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_controller, value=name), state='readonly').grid(row=0, column=2)
    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'New Name:').grid(row=1, column=1)
    new_name = Entry(self.edit_controller)
    new_name.grid(row=1, column=2)

    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'Current Position:').grid(row=2, column=1)
    Entry(self.edit_controller, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_controller, value=current_position), state='readonly').grid(row=2, column=2)
    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'New Position:').grid(row=3, column=1)
    new_position = Entry(self.edit_controller)
    new_position.grid(row=3, column=2)

    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'Current Games Played:').grid(row=4, column=1)
    Entry(self.edit_controller, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_controller, value=current_gamesplayed), state='readonly').grid(row=4, column=2)
    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'New Games Played:').grid(row=5, column=1)
    new_gamesplayed = Entry(self.edit_controller)
    new_gamesplayed.grid(row=5, column=2)        

    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'Current Goals:').grid(row=0, column=3)
    Entry(self.edit_controller, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_controller, value=current_goals), state='readonly').grid(row=0, column=4)
    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'New Goals:').grid(row=1, column=3)
    new_goals = Entry(self.edit_controller)
    new_goals.grid(row=1, column=4)

    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'Current Assists:').grid(row=2, column=3)
    Entry(self.edit_controller, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_controller, value=current_assists), state='readonly').grid(row=2, column=4)
    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'New Assists:').grid(row=3, column=3)
    new_assists = Entry(self.edit_controller)
    new_assists.grid(row=3, column=4)

    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'Current Clean Sheets:').grid(row=4, column=3)
    Entry(self.edit_controller, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_controller, value=current_cleansheets), state='readonly').grid(row=4, column=4)
    Label(self.edit_controller, text = 'New Clean Sheets:').grid(row=5, column=3)
    new_cleansheets = Entry(self.edit_controller)
    new_cleansheets.grid(row=5, column=4)

    Button(self.edit_controller, text='Save Changes', command = lambda: self.edit_records(new_name.get(), name, new_position.get(), current_position, new_gamesplayed.get(), current_gamesplayed, new_goals.get(), current_goals, new_assists.get(), current_assists, new_cleansheets.get(), current_cleansheets)).grid(row=6, column=4, sticky=E)

    self.edit_controller.mainloop()

def edit_records(self, new_name, name, new_position, current_position, new_gamesplayed, current_gamesplayed, new_goals, current_goals, new_assists, current_assists, new_cleansheets, current_cleansheets):
    query = 'UPDATE Year11 SET name = ?, position = ?, games_played = ?, goals = ?, assists = ?, clean_sheets = ? WHERE name = ?, position = ?, games played = ?, goals = ?, assists = ?, clean sheets = ?'
    parameters = (new_name, name, new_position, current_position, new_gamesplayed, current_gamesplayed, new_goals, current_goals, new_assists, current_assists, new_cleansheets, current_cleansheets)
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.edit_controller.destroy()
    self.message['text'] = 'Record {} changed.'.format(name)
    self.viewing_records()
```

**I'm inexperienced with this whole situation, so any help will be much appreciated!**

Edit:

```
run_query(self, query, parameters=()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query_result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return query_result
```

Comment: @BryanOakley Here's the more refined question.

Comment: Apparently there's an error in the SQL statement created by the function `run_query`. But it's not included in the code you've presented in your question. I would say, have another look at the syntax for the `UPDATE` statement, make `run_query` print out the statement it generates and compare that with the required syntax.

Comment: Hi @BillBell , the code for run_query is now on the original code section above. Can't work out what's up! def

Comment: please show us the exact query that is causing the error. It would also really help if you removed all of the irrelevant code. You need to create a [mcve]

Comment: I agree with @BryanOakley. Surely you should execute `run_query` for yourself to find out where it's going wrong.

Comment: There's not irrelevant code there because it's all required for the query @BryanOakley . I have fixed it anyway now through other means. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: Adam, why are you making it so hard for us to help you? All you have to do is show the query and the full error message. Until then, there's nothing we can do. We aren't being unreasonable in asking for a [mcve] -- experience has taught is that this is the best way to narrow down a problem. It helps _you_ understand precisely where the problem is and how to reproduce it. It then becomes much simpler to diagnose and fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE Year11 SET ... WHERE name = ?, position = ?, ...
```

Other than the SET clause, the WHERE clause does not take multiple expressions. You have to give it a single expression, i.e., you have to compose a big one by joining smaller ones with AND.

```
clean sheets = ?
```

The column name is `clean_sheets`.

Comment: I'd already fixed the problem, but this is what I did to resolve, so thanks for verifying!